# How can I conditionally reveal content of an asset based on day of the week?

Tags: assets, structure

I have an asset called specials. There is one special for each day of the week. On the homepage I'd like to have that days special 'magically' appear upon page load in the designated area.

Anyone have any idea how I could pull this off without the client having to go in everyday and manually change the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="specials" url_title='{current_time format="%l"}' }
```

{current_time format="%l"} will yield the current day of the week. i. e. "Monday"
Not sure how you are set up, but you get the idea.